# How can weighted averages be calculated for a Dataset summarized with GroupBy

Tags: dataset

I would like to compute market-value weighted stock prices grouped by sector from a `Dataset` but can't figure out how to apply `WeightedData` when using `GroupBy`.

Get prices:

```
prices = FinancialData[{"AAPL", "GOOG", "JPM", "C"}]
{$205.53, $1171.02, $106.80, $62.36}
```

Create dataset:

```
port = Dataset[{
   <|"Sector" -> "Tech", "Ticker" -> "AAPL", "Shares" -> 1000, "Price" -> prices[[1]]|>,
   <|"Sector" -> "Tech", "Ticker" -> "GOOG", "Shares" -> 100, "Price" -> prices[[2]]|>,
   <|"Sector" -> "Fin", "Ticker" -> "JPM", "Shares" -> 400, "Price" -> prices[[3]]|>,
   <|"Sector" -> "Fin", "Ticker" -> "C", "Shares" -> 1000, "Price" -> prices[[4]]|>
   }]
```

Add market-value to dataset:

```
port = port[All, Append[#, "MarketValue" -> #Price/100.0 * #Shares] &]
```

Weight all prices by market-value (*goal is to apply this at group level*):

```
wp = WeightedData[Normal[port[All, "Price"]], Normal[port[All, "MarketValue"]]]
```

Compute weighted mean:

```
Mean[wp]
$439.13
```

Compute mean by group:

```
port[GroupBy["Sector"], Mean, "Price"]
```

[image]

So, how can one compute weighted averages at the group level?

Comment: Does everyone with Mathematica have access to `FinancialData` or is it a separate service? I keep getting "Internet download failed..."

Comment: @alancalvitti afaik, yes.  I have been using the Home edition of Mathematica since version 10.0 and have always had access to `FinancialData`.  The documentation for version 12.0 indicates it was introduced in version 6.0 (2007).

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
weightedmean = Mean @* Apply[WeightedData] @* Transpose 

port[GroupBy["Sector"],  weightedmean,  {#Price, #MarketValue}&]
```

[image]

```
port[weightedmean, {#Price, #MarketValue}&]
```

> Quantity[439.1334211424316, "USDollars"]

Note: You can also define `weightedmean` using (easier to read?)  [`RightComposition`](https://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RightComposition.html):

```
weightedmean = Transpose /* Apply[WeightedData] /* Mean
```

Comment: I see, @* is Composition and /* is RightComposition.  Initially my preference was for Composition, as I tend to read Dataset operations from right to left, but after some experimentation the RightComposition approach seems easier to read, imo.